# Traverse inheritance tree recursively with Java

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I need to take a given record and populate a list with the identifiers of all of its child records ad infinitem (I.e. all child records of original item, all child records of children, all child records of grandchildren etc.) I currently have a method which produces what I want but it's not the most easily read and uses iteration rather than recursion. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve what I want, potentially using a recursive call but with the primary aim of making the code easier to read. Current implementation is as follows

```
public List<String> getAllChildRecords(targetRecord) {  
    
    final List<String> allChildRecordIds = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> recordIdsForQuery = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> queryResults = new ArrayList<>();

    recordIdsForQuery.add(targetRecord);

    while (!recordIdsForQuery .isEmpty()) {

        for (final String queryParentId : recordIdsForQuery ) {
            queryResults.addAll(
                    [DBAccessLayerClass].[getChildRecordIds](queryParentId));
        }

        allChildRecordIds .addAll(queryResults);
        recordIdsForQuery .clear();
        recordIdsForQuery .addAll(queryResults);
        queryResults.clear();
    }

    return allChildRecordIds
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Recursion isn't usually the right answer, especially in java - it tends to be slow, for example, and produce convoluted stack traces. Therefore, 'just rewrite to recursion' is not the slamdunk answer, and thus, not a slamdunk improvement if you're concerned about readability.

The usual trick is to work with a queue. Also, stop declaring things final 'for readability' - you're adding a ton of noise to this code. If you insist on having 'changing locals' be reduced to a minimum for readability, configure your IDE to render writes to locals in a highly visible manner, don't mess up your code by adding a bunch of noisy keywords everywhere.

```
var out = new ArrayList<String>();
var queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
queue.add(targetRecord);

while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
  String id = queue.pop();
  var childIds = DbAccessLayerClass.getChildRecordIds(id));
  out.addAll(childIds);
  queue.addAll(childIds);
}

return out;
```

If you're afraid of loops or repeats (where 1 item can be a child of multiple separate entries, for example), turn your `out` into a `(Linked)HashSet` instead, and add `childIds.removeAll(out);` right after `DbAccessLayerClass.getChildRecordIds`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep all those final keywords in place, it's not something I can change but that looks like a really interesting solution, I've not really worked with queues before. Thanks very much for the feedback, it's great :)

Comment: This is good, I'd probably add the use of `queues` vs `stacks` will give you breadth first search vs depth first search, depending on the problem domain and your understanding, you can replace the data structure to get better in practice performance

Comment: @Bhaskar `ArrayDeque` can operate in either fashion at high performance - a matter of using .pop() or `.removeLast()` to switch between depth-first and breath-first.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - agreed, you might notice I didn't say anything about an implementation.